# SIGABRT while building mono on Solaris

Tags: mono, solaris

I've been trying to build Mono 3.2.3 on Solaris 11 with no luck.  I've made a few minor code changes and turned off configuration features to get to this point but now I'm stuck with mono crashing while trying to build System.dll. Any ideas?

```
MONO_PATH="./../../class/lib/basic:$MONO_PATH" /home/axsadm/mono-3.2.3/runtime/mono-wrapper  ./../../class/lib/basic/basic.exe /codepage:65001   -d:NET_1_1 -d:NET_2_0 -d:NET_3_0 -d:NET_3_5 -d:NET_4_0 -nowarn:1699 -nostdlib -lib:./../../class/lib/build -r:mscorlib.dll -optimize  /noconfig -nowarn:618 -d:CONFIGURATION_2_0 -unsafe -resource:resources/Asterisk.wav -resource:resources/Beep.wav -resource:resources/Exclamation.wav -resource:resources/Hand.wav -resource:resources/Question.wav -target:library -out:../../class/lib/build/tmp/System.dll  @System.dll.sources
+ r=/home/axsadm/mono-3.2.3
+ MONO_CFG_DIR=/home/axsadm/mono-3.2.3/runtime/etc
+ PATH=/home/axsadm/mono-3.2.3/runtime/_tmpinst/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin
+ MONO_SHARED_DIR=/home/axsadm/mono-3.2.3/runtime
+ export MONO_CFG_DIR MONO_SHARED_DIR PATH
+ [ -n '' ]
+ exec /home/axsadm/mono-3.2.3/libtool '--mode=execute' /home/axsadm/mono-3.2.3/mono/mini/mono --config /home/axsadm/mono-3.2.3/runtime/etc/mono/config ./../../class/lib/basic/basic.exe /codepage:65001 -d:NET_1_1 -d:NET_2_0 -d:NET_3_0 -d:NET_3_5 -d:NET_4_0 -nowarn:1699 -nostdlib -lib:./../../class/lib/build -r:mscorlib.dll -optimize /noconfig -nowarn:618 -d:CONFIGURATION_2_0 -unsafe -resource:resources/Asterisk.wav -resource:resources/Beep.wav -resource:resources/Exclamation.wav -resource:resources/Hand.wav -resource:resources/Question.wav -target:library -out:../../class/lib/build/tmp/System.dll @System.dll.sources
* Assertion at threads.c:1001, condition `info' not met


Native stacktrace:

        /home/axsadm/mono-3.2.3/mono/mini/mono-boehm'mono_handle_native_sigsegv+0x1b8 [0x187c58]
        /home/axsadm/mono-3.2.3/mono/mini/mono-boehm'sigabrt_signal_handler+0xa0 [0x1ed97c]
        /lib/libc.so.1'__sighndlr+0xc [0xff0254f0]
        /lib/libc.so.1'call_user_handler+0x370 [0xff018e50]
        /lib/libc.so.1'sigacthandler+0x58 [0xff019040]
        /lib/libc.so.1'_lwp_kill+0x8 [0xff029fa0]
        /lib/libc.so.1'abort+0xc8 [0xfefaac2c]
        /home/axsadm/mono-3.2.3/mono/mini/mono-boehm'monoeg_g_logv+0x174 [0x3d5454]
        /home/axsadm/mono-3.2.3/mono/mini/mono-boehm'monoeg_assertion_message+0x38 [0x3d54e8]
        /home/axsadm/mono-3.2.3/mono/mini/mono-boehm'mono_thread_attach_full+0x2bc [0x2dc650]
        /home/axsadm/mono-3.2.3/mono/mini/mono-boehm'mono_thread_attach+0x10 [0x2dc37c]
        /home/axsadm/mono-3.2.3/mono/mini/mono-boehm'mono_runtime_init+0x23c [0x314034]
        /home/axsadm/mono-3.2.3/mono/mini/mono-boehm'mini_init+0x1a60 [0x77158]
        /home/axsadm/mono-3.2.3/mono/mini/mono-boehm'mono_main+0x232c [0x1457a4]
        /home/axsadm/mono-3.2.3/mono/mini/mono-boehm'mono_main_with_options+0x48c [0x5fa30]
        /home/axsadm/mono-3.2.3/mono/mini/mono-boehm'main+0x2c [0x5fa74]
        /home/axsadm/mono-3.2.3/mono/mini/mono-boehm'_start+0x5c [0x5f3e4]

=================================================================
Got a SIGABRT while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries
used by your application.
=================================================================

gmake[8]: *** [../../class/lib/build/tmp/System.dll] Abort (core dumped)
```

Configuration:

```
   Engine:
        GC:            included Boehm
        TLS:           pthread
        SIGALTSTACK:   no
        Engine:        Building and using the JIT
        oprofile:      no
        BigArrays:     no
        DTrace:        no
        LLVM Back End: no (dynamically loaded: no)

   Libraries:
        .NET 2.0/3.5:  yes
        .NET 4.0:      yes
        .NET 4.5:      yes
        MonoDroid:     no
        MonoTouch:     no
        JNI support:   IKVM Native
        libgdiplus:    assumed to be installed
        zlib:          system zlib
```

Answer (score 1):

This might be a bit late, but for me I had more luck using the external Boehm GC as opposed to the bundled/included one.

```
./autogen.sh --prefix=/usr --disable-dtrace --with-sgen=no --with-gc=boehm
```

This seemed to work OK for Solaris 10 and 11 on Intel.  I'm still working on SPARC!

Good luck,

Steve

Comment: Thanks Steve, any luck on SPARC?  That's what I've been working on.